# Javascript Touchstart? Zombie Game

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, touch

I am making a zombie game. You can view it at www.designedbychristian.com/u-vs-them

I had clickable div which worked. But when testing on my iphone5s and Ps vita the clickable divs lagged.

I decided to use raw javascript and avoid importing jquery mobile.

I wrote this into my code

```
    <script>
        localStorage.setItem('facing', 'right')



        function touchEvents() {

            document.getElementById('shoot').addEventListener("toustart", shoot, false);
            document.getElementById('left').addEventListener("touchstart", left, false);
            document.getElementById('right').addEventListener("touchstart", right, false);
            function shoot(e) {
                e.preventDefault()
                $('#player').append('<div id="bullet" class="bullet">');
                if (localStorage.getItem('facing') == "right") {
                    $('.bullet').animate({ "left": "1500px" }, 700, "linear", function () {
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                } else if ((localStorage.getItem('facing') == "left")) {
                    $('.bullet').animate({ "right": "1500px" }, 700, "linear", function () {
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                };
            };
            function left() {
                var p = $("#player");
                var poff = p.offset();
                var pleft = poff.left;
                if (pleft > 103) {
                    var element = document.getElementById("player");
                    element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) - 5 + 'px';
                    var bg = document.getElementById("bg");
                    bg.style.left = parseInt(bg.style.left) + 5 + 'px';
                    localStorage.setItem("facing", "left")
                } else { return false }
            }

            //right function

            function right() {

                var p = $("#player");
                var poff = p.offset();
                var pleft = poff.left;
                if (pleft < 962) {
                    var element = document.getElementById("player");
                    element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) + 5 + 'px';
                    var bg = document.getElementById("bg");
                    var zombz = document.getElementById("zombie");
                    bg.style.left = parseInt(bg.style.left) - 5 + 'px';
                    localStorage.setItem("facing", "right")
                } else { return false }

            }
        };
        window.onload = touchEvents;
        </script>
```

Now this works on my windows 8 touchscreen laptop with chrome using my touch screen not my mouse. (have not tested in ie or ff)

It does not work on anything else with a touch screen(iphone,ipad, ps vita). 
I do not know why. I have been trying to find out all day

You can look at my game further with the url above. If viewing on an iphone you must save it to your homescreen and change orientation to landscape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#player')
```

is a jQuery shortcut for

```
document.getElementById("player");
```

I would check whether you're getting the correct element.

Comment: It does not seem to matter what I add in there. even alerts will not show up

Comment: If an alert isn't showing, then that's an indication that the script isn't reaching that line of code. Can you try moving the function calls like `document.getElementById('shoot').addEventListener("toustart", shoot, false);` below the function definitions? Also, have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: I have. It was throwing a lot due to left being undefined. I ended up using jquery mobile and getting it to work. I just do not understand why it works so good on the windows 8 and on the iPhone it is just not working.

Comment: You may want to develop with a cross-platform framework. Something like [PhaserJS](http://phaser.io/)

Comment: Hmm that seems very interesting. Thank you!